# Why can't I include a tilde in a path when using Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc

@Html.Partial("~/Shared/SuccessErrorStatus")

Server Error in '/' Application.
The partial view '~/Shared/SuccessErrorStatus' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Shared/SuccessErrorStatus

It seems to give the impression the path has been searched but it doesn't seem to have resolved the path correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either complete name as Darin pointed out or use a View name only.
In this case

```
@Html.Partial("SuccessErrorStatus")
```

should work too.

Comment: Worth noting that this assumes that the partial is located in a standard location. Like ~/Views/Shared or ~/Views/CurrentController.

Comment: Thanks, I like the concise version as my view is in the shared folder.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the extension. Also you probably meant `~/Views/Shared` and not `~/Shared`. Normally all views should be located inside the `~/Views` folder:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/SuccessErrorStatus.cshtml")
```